# how to properly include a mouseover-driven change to css elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, selectors-api

First of all, I'm very new to javascript.

I'm trying to reverse the background and text colors with mouse hovering. I'd prefer to use javascript (never thought I'd say *that*), as the following code is part of a larger script, and is contingent on time/date for some things. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```js
var z = document.querySelectorAll("a,#search_button");
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
  z[i].style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
  z[i].style.color = "#FFFFFF";
        z[i].onmouseover = function () {
            z[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
            z[i].style.color = "#000000";
        }
 }
```

The first part works like a charm, setting the colors correctly. But mousing over doesn't reverse them. What did I do wrong, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you can just place this in your css sheet as well

```
#searchbutton:hover{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#000000
}
```

place this in your CSS sheet and it should do what you wanted.

Comment: when you prefer javascript ofcourse as said in the question, this answer won't do ofc.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. It's actually what I tried prior to the javascript. But it didn't work either. Thank you for trying to help, though.

Comment: ever thought about using jquery? it solves a lot of these problem too. You have a lot of tutorials about it as well and it has almost never let me down unlike the css.
http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: @rccapps have you already tried to use `object.addEventListener("mouseover", myScript); ` instead of onmouseover, should be the same, but you never know